# C# email client GUI - Inbox and Outbox designing

Tags: c#, .net, email, user-interface, frontend

I have a semester project of designing a basic email client in C#. I know that in small amount of time I won't be able to design a beautiful & complex GUI like OUTLOOK or Thunderbird.

1. I am planning to design a GUI something shown in below in figure,
   but dont know where to start from? Should I use PANELS and SPLITER tools to get this gui? [image: how to get this gui in C#]
2. Also, 2nd problem is that how to design the inbox and outbox for my
   email client. I mean how to list all the emails of inbox and outbox
   from my email server.

ps: iam using the MAILKIT/MIMEKIT as the API so I dont need to worry about the sending/receiving the email. Just need to focus on the front end.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a sample design. Basically you create a form that has a MenuStrip (dock top), ToolStrip (dock top), StatusStrip (dock bottom), TreeView (dock left) and SplitContainer (dock right).

In the SplitContainer change the orientation to horizontal (default is vertical). In the lower panel, add a WebBrowser control. This will allow you to render HTML emails. In the top panel, I suppose you could put a RichTextBox for showing a pretty email header, or a list box for listing emails received in the selected folder?

If the docking looks funny, play around with z-indexes (Send to Front, Send to Back controls until it looks right).

Using tree view allows you to display the email server's directory structure, and if you're using a listbox in top panel for email list for a folder, all should be handled.

[image: Example Design]

Comment: wow. so quick and detailed reply. I am impressed. Thank you very much first of all. In tree view,  I will be able to get the "inbox, sent, spam" folders ? and when I click on the inbox, the messages of inbox will show in panel 1 ?

Comment: one more thing is that how can I load or DISPLAY all the inbox messages in that panel 1 ? i mean i have got the messages in array. how to list all the inbox message in panel 1 ?

Comment: Yes you will be able to get the Inbox/Sent/Spam folders in the tree view. I would not recommend showing the emails in this tree view though. I'd say use the top panel to put a listbox that lists all emails for a folder.

Comment: thanks Brett, yes I will load all the emails in the panel1, my question is that should I use LISTBOX or DATAGRIDVIEW to display / list emails of my inbox ? which would be better ?

Comment: Datagrid would be best now that you mention it.